# Display second column separated by comma as sub category

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a way to convert the column B with data separated by comma into multiple rows and also as a sub category of column A whose values are unique.

Example:

```
   A        B
1      222,333,444
2      111,222,333
```

To be converted to

```
    A       B
1          222
_          333
_          444
2          111
_          222
_          333
```

_ is a separate row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the comas by a line break

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Replace ",", vbCrLf
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Range("B1").Rows.AutoFit
Next
```

---

EDIT: This should fit what you asked for

```
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
 'Define the range to be analysed
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
     'Split each string by ","
    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
    For Each strArr In tempArr
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
         'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
    Next
Next lngRow
 'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[a1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
```

I tested it and this is my output. Let me know if there is a problem.

[image]

Comment: great! But, my problem was to print it to multiple rows instead within the same?

Comment: @user3317862 Update your example to make sure I understand.

Comment: @user3317862 If I understand, in your example the dash should be replaced by 1,2,3,4,5,6...?

Comment: No given column a value until we have a corresponding column b value the column a value has to be a. The left side i.e., column a

Comment: @user3317862 the answer is now updated, if the answer works for you don't forget to click the green check mark to mark the answer as answered

Comment: I get an type mismatch error on tempArr = Split line. May be because you included lngRow which is long?

Comment: When you get the error put your mouse over temArr and lngRow and check what are the values of those variables

Comment: LngRow is 89 but tempArr doesn't have a value

Comment: No its a list of 5-6 digit numbers

Comment: If you post the code that you have in the question it could help me understand the problem

Comment: Its your edited code on the top. In the following line tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2)

Comment: Is lngRow a Long and tempArr an array of sting?

Comment: Yes it is long. All I did was I had put it in a procedure.

Comment: Show me the example you are trying to do and I'll see if I get the same problem

Comment: Can you check the chat?

Comment: I added a picture of my results